# finding coordinates on a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

[image]

The diagram shows a quadrilateral $ABCD$ in which point $A$ is $(-1,-1)$, the point $B$ is $(3,6)$ and the point $C$ is $(9,4)$. The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $M$. Angle $BMA=90$ degrees and $BM=MD$.

how do you find the coordinates of $M$ and $D$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give the steps:

- find the equation of the line, let's say, $r$, that passes through $A$ and $C$. Having two points of the line, you can do this;
- If the slope of the line $r$ is $m_r$, then the slope of the line $s$ that passes through $B$ and $M$ is $m_s$, which is determined by the relation of orthogonality: $m_r m_s = -1$. Find the equation of the line $s$ using the slope $m_s$ and the point $B$, think of point-slope form;
- the intersection of lines $r$ and $s$ is the point $M$, which you will find by solving a system;
- finally, to find $D$, use that $M$ is the middle point between $B$ and $D$.

Can you do it?

Comment: I found M, But now to get D, I am not positive what formula to use.

Comment: It's not a matter of "what formula", but just to follow your intuition. If $M$ is the middle point between $B$ and $D$, then $ (x_m, y_m) = \left( \frac{x_b + x_d}{2}, \frac{y_b + y_d}{2} \right)$.

Comment: Ok i got it. so if you were asked to then find the Ratio AM:MC, what would be the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Since you already have all the coordinates, this is straight-forward, it is just $$\frac{d(A,M)}{d(M,C)}$$

Have you studied analytic geometry yet?

Comment: Ok yeah i understand!

Comment: I haven't really studied analytic geometry in depth.

Answer (score 1):

The line $AC$ has slope $\frac{1}{2}$, so the line $BD$, being perpendicular to $AC$, must have slope $-2$. The line of slope $-2$ passing through $(3,6)$ is $y-6 = -2(x-3)$, or $y = -2x+12$. The line $AC$ has equation $y+1 = \frac{1}{2}(x+1)$, or $y = \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{2}$. You can solve for the intersection point to get $(5,2)$. Finally, the length $BM$, which you can now compute, must be the same as $MD$, and $D$ also lies on the line $y=-2x+12$; you can use this information to find the coordinates of $D$.